# Unity Multiplayer functionalities or Google's plug-in?

Tags: unity, google-play-services, unity-networking

I want to add multiplayer matches to a game I'm making for Android/PC, and something echoed in my mind: would the network functionalities Unity provides work in Android? I ask this because Google has a free plug-in for their services, but Unity also offers possibilities. Also, using any of the above, do I need to pay to rent a server? Or, for example, since we need a paid developer account to register our game at Google Play Store, the servers are part of the deal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity and Google offer different APIs/Services, but both are centred around a P2P (Peer to Peer) architecture.

Unity, as does Google, offers matchmaking and relay servers. These are ways to find players, and relay data between clients.

Unity's offering comes with a free "personal" licence, where as with Google's there seems to be some lack of information (free?).

As Unity is cross platform, it's tools and services are as well. The services provided by Google however only work on Android/iOS.

More information for Unity is here: https://unity3d.com/services/multiplayer

More information for Google is here: https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/realtimeMultiplayer

Comment: After reading what you provided, I couldn't understand the payment method. You said Unity has a free "personal" license, how so?

Comment: @Evenilink https://store.unity.com/ states Unity Multiplayer as 20 Concurrent Users. More information is provided on the page.

Comment: That's exactly my question! So basic users can have 20 players worldwide playing at the same time, right? Guess this is more to test multiplayer itself than providing a "true" free service, but I understand they need the income to keep servers running...